# Xampp IP changed - htdocs files missing

Tags: php, apache, xampp

So ive been using xampp for a virtual server for an app ive been making. I dont know much about xampp but its been working fine all along. I have been using my php files in the htdocs folder. Today the ip address changed from 192.168.64.2 to 192.168.64.3 and now all my files are missings. Is there any way to recover these files. I'm using a Mac Book.

Any help at all is appreciated

Comment: huh, is not xampp can be installed locally? or perhaps you are using a vm? or... what? its pretty unclear..

Comment: What happens if you go to http://localhost?

Comment: Do you mean that your web server (XAMPP) is on a different PC from the one you are on?

Comment: apologies. Im not using a virtual machine, I normally go to the volumes tab and press mount then explore and find the files through that but now its only all the default files in there as if i set up a new server

Comment: It is on the same PC

Answer (score 1):

Don't use your network internal IP. You are using DHCP and it's gonna change periodically. Just use **http://127.0.0.1** or **http://localhost**. If you had your website URL declared as http://192.168.64.2 at some config file, just replace it for the values provided above.

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway now that it already changed to get the files back that were using the old ip address or are they lost?

Comment: Files are not lost. You just cannot reach them by using that IP address. Please try with the addresses I provided in my answer. If you can fetch the homepage, then you can replace all the  http://192.168.64.2 with http://localhost in your code ...